# Difference between SDBM_File hash and normal hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

when it is required to use SDBM_File hash instead of normal Perl has ? what is it that  SDBM_File hash can accomplish that normal Perl hash cannot?
I read docs here https://perldoc.perl.org/SDBM_File.html  and  http://docs.w3cub.com/perl~5.26/sdbm_file/ , but I am just wondering why can't Perl hash be used to achieve what in place of of a SDBM file DB?

Comment: `SDBM_File` is not a hash at all. It's a keyed-value disk storage module that provides a hash-like variable as interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is that an `SDBM_File` hash (and any of Perl's DBM file implementations) is that the hash is stored in an external file.

If you store data in a standard Perl hash, then that hash only exists as long as your program is running. When the program ends, your hash disappears and any data in the hash vanishes into thin air. The next time you run your program, the hash will start out empty again.

If you store data in a DBM file hash, then any change to the hash is written to a file. When your program ends, that file still exists. So when you run your program again, the data is reloaded from the file and is still there for you to use.

Most of the time you'll want a transient hash that only exists while the program is running. If you want persistent data, then a DBM hash might be what you want (although, to be honest, these days most people would just use a database).

Comment: Thanks Dave,Does perl automatically appends .pag to the external file that SDBM write s to/ read from?I did not really understand the thing about .dir and .pag on the perldoc link

Comment: @Vicky: There are actually two files created for each hash. One with the extension `.pag` contains the "pages" of data and one with the extension `.dir` contains the "directory" (an index of where each piece of data is stored). And, yes, Perl adds those extensions to the hash file name that you give to the `tie` command. But really, there is very little need to use DBM files now that we have high-quality open source databases like SQLite and PostgreSQL.

Comment: (@Vicky: You can change the extensions that Perl automatically adds. But no-one ever does. And you shouldn't either.)

Comment: Thanks much Dave for quick and concise explanation